# Why synchronized parent class is not blocking for the below code?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.util.Date;

class AppParent {
    public synchronized void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(new Date() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Inside AppParent");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(new Date() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Exiting AppParent");
    }
}

class AppChild extends AppParent {
    public synchronized void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(new Date() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Inside AppChild");
        super.doSomething();
        System.out.println(new Date() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Exiting AppChild");
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AppParent().doSomething();
            }
        });
        t1.setName("Thread 1");

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AppChild().doSomething();
            }
        });
        t2.setName("Thread 2");

        t1.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Mon May 26 17:45:02 IST 2014 : Thread 1 Inside AppParent
Mon May 26 17:45:03 IST 2014 : Thread 2 Inside AppChild
Mon May 26 17:45:03 IST 2014 : Thread 2 Inside AppParent
Mon May 26 17:45:17 IST 2014 : Thread 1 Exiting AppParent
Mon May 26 17:45:18 IST 2014 : Thread 2 Exiting AppParent
Mon May 26 17:45:18 IST 2014 : Thread 2 Exiting AppChild
```

My question:
If Thread 1 is inside parent class synchronized method(where it will spend 15 secs), how Thread 2 enters into the same synchronized block??

What I expected is that Thread 2 Inside AppParent would have been printed after 15 sec from when Thread 1 Inside AppParent is printed.

Can someone pls explain.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can enter since its the critical section of a different object. (Same class, but different object.)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    new AppParent().doSomething();
}
```

You syncronize for the object. Making a new object makes a new synchronization monitor that the other Thread can enter.

Comment: if a code is synchronized, only one thread can access it. correct??

Comment: thanks, got it...It has to be the same lock for both the threads.